# How to execute Python code within React app?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, axios

I need to parse a web page and display a result in React component. Due to CORS, I'm unable easily access that page from my application, while python makes this in a few lines.

As I read in multiple similar answers, the key is to make ajax request to python code.

So, what I'm doing:

```
axios.post('../../assets/wordnik.py').then(res => console.log(res))
```

Plain and simple, though I get the following error:
[image]

So, how can I fix this and what is wrong exactly?

UPD. Python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.wordnik.com/randoml"
f = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
h1s = soup("h1")
h1 = h1s[0].getText().strip()
print(h1)
```

Comment: You got a 404 error it's not due to CORS, did you start a python webserver in order to access to you file ? 
If you want to render a page you can use an react iframe component for it

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon I mean that I can't use JS to access that page due to CORS and that's why I try to use python. No, could you elaborate on *python webserver* and make it an answer

Comment: If both python and react app are hosted on the same domain, then CORS issue will not occur. Else, you need to enable the CORS on server side. Not sure which framework you are using, but you can google it, how to enable CORS in python, based on your framework.

Comment: can you provide your python code ?

Comment: @MohitPandey as I mentioned in earlier comment, CORS is not the problem with python, but the reason I need to use python over js

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon edited the question. It is just a few lines

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot access/execute python code using JS. If you are trying to fetch the response from python code, then you need to expose it as an API, which can then be consumed by React using `axios`. Same applicable for `POST` request as well.

Comment: @MohitPandey I see, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dropping a python script in your react app source doesn't magically turn it into an API entry point. The script has to be executed by a python process, and you must have an HTTP server mapping this process to an url, passing the request to the process and forwarding the response. Plain, basic HTTP backend programming stuff actually.

The prefered way to server a python backend app is the `wsgi` protocol, which is supported one way or another by the main HTTP servers (apache, nginx etc). You can write your script directly to the wsgi spec, or use an existing wgsi framework (`flask` comes to mind for simple, lightweight apps like your).